# Tensorflow r1.0 : could not a find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, installation

I want to install Tensorflow 1.o for python on windows.

**This is information for my system.**

```
D:\>python --version
Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (32-bit)

D:\>pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from d:\web\anaconda\lib\site-packages (python 3.5)'
```

**But, when I execute below command,**

```
D:\>pip3 install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I don't understand what the problem is...

And I tried another way...

**This is case when I use Conda**

```
(tensorflow) D:\>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl
tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: tensorflow doesn't support python 32 bit it requires python 64 bit

Answer (score 125):

I was in same problem.

Below command solved my problem

```
pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

to find the list of all the urls based on the python version and CPU or GPU only refer to:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: what about gpu link?

Comment: Answer should acknowledge the top answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip

Comment: when i install tensorflow using this command, i still cannot use keras in my code. Gives the error tensorflow cannot be found. What is the solution for that

Comment: @Gethma there are no links to many versions.. this should not be the solution.........

Comment: @ceounii lee, Hey dude, accept this as an answer, it works.

Answer (score 53):

Tensorflow requires a 64-bit version of Python.

Additionally, [it only supports](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) Python 3.5.x through Python 3.8.x.

If you're using a 32-bit version of Python or a version that's too old or new, then you'll get that error message.

To fix it, you can install the 64-bit version of Python 3.8.6 via [Python's website](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

Comment: I have Python 3.6 64-Bit but still I am getting the same error on Windows 10

Comment: The other important missing piece of information for me was that the `pip install...` command needed to be run with Administrator privileges... otherwise it failed to install the `six` package.

Comment: downgraded python 3.6 to 3.5 and it seems installing. Not throwing any error.

Comment: I also had to ugrade pip to make it work with python 3.5

Answer (score 19):

Tensorflow on windows needs python 3.5. You can follow following steps to activate python 3.5 in anaconda:

1. See which version of python you have: `conda search python`
2. If you already have python 3.5 then go to step 3
   otherwise use `conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda` to create python 3.5
3. Activate python 3.5 using `activate py35`
4. Now install tensorflow using `conda install tensorflow`

If step4 is not working i.e, something like "tensorflow: no package found " then follow [this](https://github.com/conda-forge/tensorflow-feedstock) tutorial to forge `conda-forge` channel and then try installing tensorflow using step4. It worked for me.

Comment: This is the first one that worked for me after trying several attempts.

Comment: Based on this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) we should use pip for installation, since conda package is community maintained.

Answer (score 8):

**Try this**

**Installing with Anaconda**

```
conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
conda install jupyter
conda install scipy
pip install tensorflow
or
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

It is important to add python=3.5 at the end of the first line, because it will install Python 3.5.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error

1. Get Python 3.5
2. Upgrade pip version to 9
3. Install tensorflow

It worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I did it with:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Answer (score 3):

From your python version output, looks like that you are using Anaconda python, in that case, there is a simple way to install tensorflow.

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

This command will take care of all dependencies like upgrade/downgrade etc.

Answer (score 1):

upgrading `pip` worked for me

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

i had python 3.8.5 ..but it will not work with tenserflow..

so i installed python 3.7.9 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was sooo dumb!!

I was using Python 3.8 in my environment. I made a new environment using Python 3.7, and the install worked fine.

[source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39130#issuecomment-623179888)

Answer (score 0):

The TensorFlow package couldn't be found by the latest version of the "pip".
To be honest, I really don't know why this is...
but, the quick fix that worked out for me was:
[In case you are using a virtual environment]
downgrade the virtual environment to python-3.8.x and pip-20.2.x
In case of anaconda, try:

```
conda install python=3.8
```

This should install the latest version of python-3.8 and pip-20.2.x for you.
And then, try

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Again, this worked fine for me, not sure if it'll work the same for you.

Answer (score -1):

The Reason is that **TensorFlow is only available upto python versions <= 3.6**. **You can't download tensorflow for python versions > 3.6** as there is no tensorflow.

If you don't want to downgrade your entire python version for a single package, do this:

1. create a new virtual environment for that project (using anaconda)
   `conda create -n <env_name> python=3.6.8`
2. activate the created environment using `conda activate <env_name>`
3. Now install `pip install tensorflow`

note: If tensorflow dosen't install : try install **keras** module first and then try installing **tensorflow**

Comment: My solution had worked exactly for me and my friends when we had ran through the same error, So I just posted a solution for the error which will solve and make program work fine. Alsp python <3.6 and >3.6 have no syntax changes, so there is no issues from migration of version.

Comment: If my answer is inaccurate, then prove in any way thay my solution is not working for this error.

Comment: The OP stated that the python version is `Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (32-bit)` so your answer is not tackle it. Also from the Tensorflow document it stated that it does support Python version 3.6 and 3.7 on Windows.