# Unable to install tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow. i need help in tensorflow installation

I am trying to install tensorflow on windows 7 32bit machine but I am getting the following error :
*"Could not find a version which satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) 
No matching distribution found for tensorflow"* [Error Message screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbup3.png)

Python version -  Python 3.5.4

I am trying to install it using pip3 install

I have tried the same installation on Ubuntu 16.0 version also but I am getting the same error

please help me to solve this installation problem

Thanks

Comment: I think this is similar to what you have asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317075/tensorflow-r1-0-could-not-a-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow r1.0 : could not a find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317075/tensorflow-r1-0-could-not-a-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tens)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Tensorflow doesn't support 32 bit architecture.
Please refer similar issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32315