# How to install tensorflow on python installed in linuxbrew (libstdc++.so.6 not found)?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, ubuntu-14.04, libstdc++, linuxbrew

I have the following version of Python installed via `linuxbrew` on Ubuntu 14.04. But `pip` gives me the following error when I tried to install `tensorflow`. Does anybody know whether there is a way to fix the problem?

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.14

$ pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I use Python 2 instead of 3. The previous question is about Python 3.

I have also tried this. But it does not work.

```
$ pip install  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/debian/jessie/tensorflow-1.9.0rc2-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
Collecting tensorflow==1.9.0rc2 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/debian/jessie/tensorflow-1.9.0rc2-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
  Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/debian/jessie/tensorflow-1.9.0rc2-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl (51.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51.6MB 320kB/s 
Collecting astor>=0.6.0 (from tensorflow==1.9.0rc2)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/35/6b/11530768cac581a12952a2aad00e1526b89d242d0b9f59534ef6e6a1752f/astor-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools<=39.1.0 in ./.linuxbrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.9.0rc2) (36.5.0)
Collecting gast>=0.2.0 (from tensorflow==1.9.0rc2)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/78/ff794fcae2ce8aa6323e789d1f8b3b7765f601e7702726f430e814822b96/gast-0.2.0.tar.gz
Collecting protobuf>=3.4.0 (from tensorflow==1.9.0rc2)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/78/a7f1ce761e2c738e209857175cd4f90a8562d1bde32868a8cd5290d58926/protobuf-3.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (390kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 399kB 5.1MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in ./.linuxbrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.9.0rc2) (1.11.0)
Collecting enum34>=1.1.6 (from tensorflow==1.9.0rc2)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/db/e56e6b4bbac7c4a06de1c50de6fe1ef3810018ae11732a50f15f62c7d050/enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting absl-py>=0.1.6 (from tensorflow==1.9.0rc2)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/86/67f55488ec68982270142c340cd23cd2408835dc4b24bd1d1f1e114f24c3/absl-py-0.4.1.tar.gz (88kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 5.1MB/s 
Collecting backports.weakref>=1.0rc1 (from tensorflow==1.9.0rc2)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/88/ec/f598b633c3d5ffe267aaada57d961c94fdfa183c5c3ebda2b6d151943db6/backports.weakref-1.0.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in ./.linuxbrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.9.0rc2) (0.30.0)
Collecting tensorboard<1.10.0,>=1.9.0 (from tensorflow==1.9.0rc2)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d5/98/e2e9d5afbc86cef0b2dd0f4ab791519b9bd305ea207e1e5c2f9a9f2f6da6/tensorboard-1.9.0-py2-none-any.whl (3.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.3MB 3.3MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in ./.linuxbrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.9.0rc2) (1.14.0)
Collecting mock>=2.0.0 (from tensorflow==1.9.0rc2)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/35/f187bdf23be87092bd0f1200d43d23076cee4d0dec109f195173fd3ebc79/mock-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 4.5MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in ./.linuxbrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.9.0rc2) (1.1.0)
Collecting grpcio>=1.8.6 (from tensorflow==1.9.0rc2)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/99/ec/8545ffc34b5d0dca66261dabaa8bc44b93e8e1df3549792d9a5649f507cf/grpcio-1.14.2-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (9.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 9.2MB 1.7MB/s 
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8 (from tensorboard<1.10.0,>=1.9.0->tensorflow==1.9.0rc2)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6d/7d/488b90f470b96531a3f5788cf12a93332f543dbab13c423a5e7ce96a0493/Markdown-2.6.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 5.0MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: futures>=3.1.1; python_version < "3" in ./.linuxbrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorboard<1.10.0,>=1.9.0->tensorflow==1.9.0rc2) (3.2.0)
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.10 (from tensorboard<1.10.0,>=1.9.0->tensorflow==1.9.0rc2)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/c4/12e3e56473e52375aa29c4764e70d1b8f3efa6682bef8d0aae04fe335243/Werkzeug-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (322kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 327kB 5.3MB/s 
Collecting funcsigs>=1; python_version < "3.3" (from mock>=2.0.0->tensorflow==1.9.0rc2)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/cb/f5be453359271714c01b9bd06126eaf2e368f1fddfff30818754b5ac2328/funcsigs-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pbr>=0.11 (from mock>=2.0.0->tensorflow==1.9.0rc2)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/1c/98cba002ed975a91a0294863d9c774cc0ebe38e05bbb65e83314550b1677/pbr-4.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (100kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 6.5MB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: gast, absl-py
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for gast ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/py/.cache/pip/wheels/9a/1f/0e/3cde98113222b853e98fc0a8e9924480a3e25f1b4008cedb4f
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for absl-py ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/py/.cache/pip/wheels/78/a3/a3/689120b95c26b9a21be6584b4b482b0fda0a1b60efd30af558
Successfully built gast absl-py
Installing collected packages: astor, gast, protobuf, enum34, absl-py, backports.weakref, markdown, werkzeug, tensorboard, funcsigs, pbr, mock, grpcio, tensorflow
Successfully installed absl-py-0.4.1 astor-0.7.1 backports.weakref-1.0.post1 enum34-1.1.6 funcsigs-1.0.2 gast-0.2.0 grpcio-1.14.2 markdown-2.6.11 mock-2.0.0 pbr-4.2.0 protobuf-3.6.1 tensorboard-1.9.0 tensorflow-1.9.0rc2 werkzeug-0.14.1
$ python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Feb 25 2018, 06:50:45) 
[GCC 5.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/py/.linuxbrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/py/.linuxbrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/py/.linuxbrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/py/.linuxbrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/py/.linuxbrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/py/.linuxbrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

But the file is available.

```
$ ls ~/.linuxbrew/lib/libstdc++.so.6
.linuxbrew/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow r1.0 : could not a find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317075/tensorflow-r1-0-could-not-a-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tens)

Comment: Is the python version x86 or x64? As tensorflow generally need x64 bit python

Comment: 64bit. $ python -c 'import struct;print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))'
64