# I can't install Tensorflow library on my Computer [PYTHON]

Tags: python, tensorflow, cmd

I am trying the install Tensorflow lib with

`pip install tensorflow`

but my computer gave me this message

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow r1.0 : could not a find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317075/tensorflow-r1-0-could-not-a-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I want to clarify, this answer is possibly incorrect due to the fact that I can not comment asking for clarification on versions. I do not have 50 reputation at present time. If it does not work, I apologize.*

Well there are two things that can be happening. When I tested this, I was able to install Tensorflow using the same console command that you did. Although I am running Python 3.8.3. Try updating python, and updating Pip.

(To update pip, simply type "`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`" and to update python, reinstall it.)

If that doesn't work, use Karthik's response of directly referencing the link to the repository of Tensorflow. Command being - "`pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl`". Hopefully that helps.

Comment: You are more than welcome! I am very glad it helped. I can actually post comments now!