# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.2.1 ? pip cannot find tensroflow 1 versions

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, virtualenv

I cannot install any tensorflow 1 version in my virtual env.. it is required by a project that I'm trying to run..

```
pip install tensorflow==1.2.1
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.2.1 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.2.1
```

Tried things suggested here :

[Tensorflow r1.0 : could not a find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317075/tensorflow-r1-0-could-not-a-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tens)

my python version is not old : 3.8.5

my pip version is OK : 20.0.2

i still CANNOT install tensorflow 1.2.1 ...

what i gotta do.. I am using ubuntu 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip:

> System requirements:
>
> - Python 3.5–3.8
>
>   - Python 3.8 support requires TensorFlow 2.2 or later.

There are two options:

1. Use older version of python (3.5-3.7)
2. Use TensorFlow 2.2 or later