# Installing tensorflow on windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install tensorflow on windows. I have python3 (3.5.2) and pip3 (9.0.1):

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

Collecting tensorflow

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Found this issue here as well: [tensorflow not found in pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-in-pip)
but none of the solutions worked for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the all answers, especially [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41750242/6153990)? And what version is your Windows? (ex: Win10 64bit) Have you installed Anaconda or Python 2? So many information missing in your question.

Comment: Yes, I tired the suggestions there - I mentioned this in the question.
Windows 8 64bit.
I have Anaconda and python 2 but I am using python3 distribution from python.org. Is Anaconda still relevant somehow?

Comment: If possible, uninstall Anaconda and Python 2, then try everything again. If still no luck, uninstall Python 3 and reinstall it. Don't forget to reboot after every uninstall. And make sure your `pip` (by `pip -V`) and `python` is running in stock Python 3 install directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following at a Python command prompt:

```
import platform
platform.architecture()[0]
```

It should display '64bit'
Just having an x86 version of Python isn't enough.
I had the same problem. Thought I had a 64 bit installation but it turned out to be 32 bit.

BTW. it will also work fine with the Conda Python 3.6 distribution. And indeed use the distro from the Gohlke page as indicated by Guillaume Jacquenot.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently x86 installation is associated with 32 bit. Installed the right version and everything works fine

Comment: Good! I think it's a bit weird that 32 bit is still the default.

Answer (score 3):

You can download binary wheel from [Christoph Gohlke's webpage](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow)

Once downloaded, you can run `pip install  tensorflow‑1.0.1‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl` for Python 3.5 64 bit

Comment: Tried this. Still get an error:
tensorflow‑1.0.1‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Comment: Are you using the 32-bit version of Python ,perhaps? Also, make sure pip and setuptools are up to date.

Comment: x86 version of python 3.5 from python.org
pip3 version 9.0.1 is up to date. What is setuptools?

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.
Currently, Tensorflow only works with 64-bit windows, not 32-bit.
So, you could create a new 64-bit environment and install tensorflow in it:

```
set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=
conda create --name name_of_your_created_environment python=3.5
activate name_of_your_created_environment
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1 sets to a 32-bit environment whilst CONDA_FORCE_32BIT= sets to a 64-bit environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog over this topic, you might find it interesting and helpful:

*Mainly issue that people face is they install 32 bit python:*

**Solution as follows**

Install Python 3.6 (Note down installation path, or simply custom install to C:\Python36) in your system - Make sure that Python is of "x64" architecture.

> To check your python architecture

```
Import platform
platform.architecture()[0]
```

Link to download Python36 with 64 bit architecture : https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.2/python-3.6.2-amd64.exe

> For more info you can follow the this link
>   https://tensorflowwindows.quora.com/

Comment: What does this add to the accepted answer, apart from the link to your blog?

Answer (score 0):

```
 pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

try this one under your python environment

Answer (score 0):

Just follow 3 steps:
Install python 3.5.x version (64bit MUST)
Install pip
pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0

And you are good to go. 
Found this after struggling for days

Comment: @Sanip Please refrain from changing the "voice" of a post when editing.

Comment: user8736771 Please consider the part of Sanips edit which (I think) improved the formatting and readability of your post. Also, adding some explanation to your answer wouldprobably improve it even more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Python 3.7 to download end version of Tensorflow ->2.3 and some packages:

1. visual studio tools C++
2. cuda_10.1.105_418.96_win10

Answer (score -2):

After spending hours I am able to fix TensorFlow installation issue on Windows. here is the summary https://stackoverflow.com/a/50475864/1996802