# Not able to install Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

> pip install tensorflow

Collecting tensorflow

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow

For info I am using Window 10 and Python 3.5.2
please help

Comment: Are you using this tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) ?  
 It says you should rather use 'pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow' or ' pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu'

Comment: Did it solve your problem ?

Comment: No,                                                                                                        
>pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow                                                         
'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: C:\Users\Sudhit>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp34-cp34m-window.whl
tensorflow-1.1.0-cp34-cp34m-window.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.                                                                                                                                          How will I know which will be supported wheel for my platform?

Comment: Are you using python2 or 3 ? Apparently tensor flow only works for python3 on windows for some reason...

Comment: I am using python 3.5.2

Comment: This question has already an answer.
Look https://stackoverflow.com/a/42596864/6560462

Comment: This question has already an answer.
Look https://stackoverflow.com/a/42596864/6560462