# install tensorflow on cygwin error

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

I am new to linux and try to install tensorflow on cygwin on a windows 7 machine with only CPU following [this instruction](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux).

I tried to install with native pip however encountered some errors when running this command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

(I omitted sudo since there's no sudo on my cygwin). The error message is:

```
tensorflow-1.2.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

The python 3 on my cygwin is 3.6.1, pip3 version is 9.0.1.

Here are some basic command result:

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.1

$ whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz

$ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/ActiveState Komodo Edit 10:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Application Virtualization Client:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Pandoc:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/PuTTY:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/1E/NomadBranch:/cygdrive/c/Users/jinhuwang/AppData/Local/rodeo/app-2.5.2/bin
```

I've seem many related question on stackoverflow but got no luck to find the solution to mine. Could anyone help?

Comment: Cygwin on Windows != Linux → the platform error

Comment: There are actually windows packages of Tensorflow (e.g. tensorflow-1.3.0-cp36-cp36m-win_x86_64.whl), however they are for x86_64 (or amd) platforms, while cygwin pip shows:
`>>> import pip
>>> print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())
[('cp36', 'cp36m', 'cygwin_2_9_0_x86_64'),`

I wonder if there is a way to force cygwin to allow x86_64 even if it is not "cygwin_2_9_0" certified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [cygwin's frontpage](https://www.cygwin.com/):

> Cygwin is not:
>
> - a way to run native Linux apps on Windows. You must rebuild your application from source if you want it to run on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.