# Issue while installing Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

While installing tensorflow(CPU only) I am facing below error :

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'

I have python version 3.5

Comment: I am having the same problem, with python 2.7. Did you manage to solve this issue ?

Comment: open cmd.exe as administrator and then import tensorflow

Comment: You might be  having multiple versions of Python, probably 2.7 and 3.5.
Tensorflow may be installed for 2.7.
You may try `pip3 install  tensorflow`

Comment: Go to the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip/53902736?noredirect=1#comment94650444_53902736

Answer (score 0):

Did you first try:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe due to some missing .py files. Download the package from [Github link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) and paste it on python35/Lib/site-packages

Answer (score 0):

> import tensorflow as tf

invokes tensorflow not install it there is great article how to install on tensorflow [website](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup).

You have not mentioned platform/OS you working on also steps taken if any before trying this command.

best thing for beginners I feel is [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/what-is-anaconda/) which is suit of packages required for data science.

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

You can search for the appropriate version you wish to install and update in the above mentioned url.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install an old version of Tensorflow as:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.5.0
```

After installing the old version retry with the newest version, for example:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.9.0
```