# Unable to install Tensorflow using pip

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install Tensorflow but it gives the following error. I have python 3.5.4 on my system and using windows 10 as my operating system
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tensorflow not found in pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-in-pip)

Comment: Any other way of  installing Tensorflow?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/

Comment: i have already used conda and pip. Nothing helped.

Comment: Then add details of the errors you got...

Comment: This is all that i have got. I have installed anaconda also but my system doesn't detect conda as any internal command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Python 3.5.4 is based on 32 bit architecture. But Tensorflow needs a 64 bit based architecture. So replacing the version 3.5.4 with 3.5.3 will work as the version 3.5.3 is a 64-bit based architecture. And the Tensorflow will install with the normal command in pip.

Answer (score 0):

What python do you have and is Python in your path?

try

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

or also

```
python -m pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Worked for me on a PC with Python 3.

Comment: i have python 3.5.4 on my system and yes python has its path set.
I have tried above commands but same issue follows up.