# tensorflow installation error in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04LTS 32-bit operating system, and I am trying to install (cpu-only python3.5) tensorflow with virtualenv using steps in:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux

When I reach to step no. 5 and 6 an error occurred:

If i use `$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` this error happen:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
>
> No matching distribution found for tensorflow

although pip version > 8.1

If i use:

```
$ export tfBinaryURL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.4.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

$ pip3 install --upgrade tfBinaryURL
```

This error happen:

> tensorflow-1.4.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64 is not a supported wheel on this platform.

How i can solve this problem ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tensorflow not found in pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-in-pip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TensorFlow binaries are only available for 64-bit platforms, while you have a 32-bit Linux installation. You should really install a 64-bit Linux instead of a 32-bit one.