# No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.4.1

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, tensorflow, rasa-nlu

I'm trying to install Rasa Core
so I installed

```
pip install rasa_core
```

...and then I tried to install the development dependencies:

```
pip install -r dev-requirements.txt
pip install -e
```

...but I get this error:

```
(base) C:\Users\\\rasa_core>pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting apscheduler==3.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached APScheduler-3.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting fakeredis==0.9.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached fakeredis-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting future==0.16.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
Collecting graphviz==0.7.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached graphviz-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting h5py==2.7.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading h5py-2.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (1.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.9MB 3.9MB/s
Collecting jsonpickle==0.9.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Using cached jsonpickle-0.9.4.tar.gz
Collecting keras==2.0.8 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached Keras-2.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.14.0 in f:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
Collecting pandoc==1.0.0b2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
  Using cached pandoc-1.0.0b2.tar.gz
Collecting redis==2.10.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
  Using cached redis-2.10.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six==1.11.0 in f:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
Collecting tensorflow==1.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13)) (from versions: 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Try to manually install via `pip install tensorflow` then run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: I installed anaconda and then installed pip install tensorflow and it's installed successfully but still the error is appearing

Comment: Mixing anaconda and pip isn't recommended

Comment: so what shall I do?

Comment: Do a fresh install of [Anaconda](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Windows-x86_64.exe) and install `rasa_core` again.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Try below command.

`python -m pip install --upgrade`

https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip)

Quick answer - Requires Python 64 bit

Credit - [@rocket1037's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41084963/3882482)