# Can't install tensorflow with pip or anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow

Does anyone know how to properly install tensorflow on Windows?

I'm currently using Python 3.7 (also tried with 3.6) and every time I get the same "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu" error

I tried installing using pip and anaconda, both don't work for me.

---

Found a solution, seems like Tensorflow doesn't support versions of python after 3.6.4. This is the version I'm currently using and it works.

Comment: Have you followed the [installation guides](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)?

Comment: `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu` is working for me in windows 10 with Python 3. [Check this out for installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/#download-and-setup)

Comment: I did follow the installation guide and tried both pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow and pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Tensorflow** or **Tensorflow-gpu** is supported only for 3.5.X versions of Python. Try installing with any Python 3.5.X version. This should fix your problem.

Comment: Or upgrade pip with `pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 4):

Here is what i did to get tensorflow working with windows.

Download python 3.7.0 (64 bit from Python Releases for Windows) Install it and check python version by running below command in cmd:

```
python --version
```

Python 3.7.0

Then run below command to upgrade pip to latest

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Now install tensorflow using pip

```
pip install tensorflow
```

That's it you have installed tensorflow on windows. Below image shows what happens when you type above commands

link for tensorflow for python 3x

https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files

tensorflow-1.14.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (68.3 MB)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, tensorflow can't installed correctly on python 3.7 and last version of anaconda: so, the best and effective way to do this is to downgrade your python to python 3.6.7 use the next steps:
1- download the latest version of Anaconda 
**use Anaconda prompt with administrator privilege** 
2- conda install python=3.6.7 **(need a long time)**
3-conda install tensorflow
4- conda install keras
5- conda install numpy

[image]

Comment: This issue was already [reported](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20444).

Answer (score 1):

- Check whether you have a CPU or GPU, if your system doesn't have GPU, then it will generate error.
- If you are going to install tensorflow using Windows command prompt (assuming python is already installed), then just run the following command. Go to the root directory, preferably 'C:' drive then run

  - For GPU-    `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu`
  - For CPU- `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`
- If you are using Anaconda, then open Anaconda Navigator->Environments->Select 'All' from the drop down menu and then search TensorFlow. If you are using CPU, then select 'tensorflow', else for GPU select 'tensorflow-gpu'. Then click Apply.

[Screenshot of Anaconda Navigator-In case you are not familiar where to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQjci.png)

Answer (score 1):

As of July 2019, I have installed it on python 3.7.3 using `py -3 -m pip install tensorflow-gpu`
py -3 in my installation selects the version 3.7.3. 
The installation can also fail if the python installation is not 64 bit. Install a 64 bit version first.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the latest version of anaconda from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)
   I'm using Anaconda 2019.03 for Windows Installer, Python 3.7, 64-bit
2. Upgrade pip as:

   > python -m pip install --upgrade pip
3. (a).    Install tensorflow using pip3 as:

   > pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow

   (b).    If you installed anaconda with all users mode. The above
   command will become:

   > pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
4. Check installation success as:

   > python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"

Answer (score 1):

As of Feb 2020, Tensorflow is not supported for Python 3.8+

To make it work install a virtualenv w/ Python 3.7 from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow pip installation for python version 3.5-3.8 requires pip 19.0 or later, as mentioned in the [official tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).

Here is [a part of this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements) documentation:

> System requirements
>
> - Python 3.5–3.8
>
>   Python 3.8 support requires TensorFlow 2.2 or later.
> - pip 19.0 or later (requires manylinux2010 support)

Try running `pip install --upgrade pip` inside your python3 virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned Anaconda. Do you run your python through there?

If so check in Anaconda Navigator --> Environments, if your current environment have got tensorflow installed. 
If not, install tensorflow and run from that environment. 
Should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that yours, happened that I had python at version 3.7. So for installing the Tensorflow with the GPU support I used:

py -3.6 -m pip install tensorflow-gpu

at a Virtualenv ambient. You can see the documentation behind on this website:

https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html

I think that this solution is better than downgrade the Python version.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the easiest way to install tensorflow is:
install python 3.5 (not 3.6 or 3.7) you can check wich version you have by typing "python" in the cmd.

When you install it check in the options that you install pip with it and you add it to variables environnement.
When its done just go into the cmd and tipe "pip install tensorflow"

It will download tensorflow automatically.

If you want to check that it's been installed type "python" in the cmd then some that ">>>" will appear, then you write "import tensorflow" and if there's no error, you've done it!

Answer (score 0):

As of November 2018, Tensorflow is **not** supported for Python 3.6.4+

**What to do:**

*Downgrade Anaconda's Python from 3.7 or 3.6.5+ to 3.6.4*

a. Open Command Prompt, find your Anaconda environment, and change your directory

- `where anaconda` or `where python`

  - Example path and cd:
  - `cd C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\bin`

b. While in anaconda3/bin in your Command Prompt, source activate your base Anaconda environment

- `source activate`

c. In your Command Prompt, downgrade your base Anaconda environment

- `conda install python=3.6.4`

d. Install Tensorflow

- `pip install tensorflow`

Further reading:
http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#how-do-i-get-the-latest-anaconda-with-python-3-5

Answer (score 0):

This is Manas working as a intern in COE-AI lab(CET,BBSR) under tech machindra.

We faced same error. After a little research, we found that there is a glitch in anaconda python `3.7`. It does not install tensorflow through pip or conda install command, even if it does..produces same error..

Here is the solution, install conda environment for `python=3.6`:

1. go to the directory where conda is installed
2. cd anaconda3
3. conda create -n tensorflow  python=3.6
4. conda activate tensorflow
5. conda install tensorflow python=3.6
6. python
7. Import tensorflow.

[steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgqJ6.png)

Do it twice: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeX4K.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY85U.png)

Answer (score 0):

**-> Not able to install tensorflow , Here I have a solution that worked for me**

**Step 1 :**
- Check version of python(3.7.3)
- Python must be 64 bit Otherwise tensorflow never ever going to be installed it defiitely gives Error.

**Step 2 :**

```sh
pip install tensorflow==2.0.0
```

**Step 3 :**

```
pip install sklearn==0.0
pip install Pillow==8.0.1
pip install h5py==2.10.0
```

**Step 4 :**

```sh
pip install keras==2.3.1
```

**Now its ready to use.**

Comment: you shouldn't need to install keras separately. It ships as part of Tensorflow 2. You'll also want a more updated version of tensorflow now.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 with Python 3.8.5, first i tried directly then it was giving following error:

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15 (from versions: none)**

Then i installed successfully in virtual environment shown below:

```
PS E:\udemy\full_stack_web_ai\deeplearning> .\myenv\Scripts\activate
(myenv) PS E:\udemy\full_stack_web_ai\deeplearning> pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow ###
Downloading tensorflow-2.4.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (370.7 MB)
```

Use virtual environment using:

```
python -m venv myenv
.\myenv\Scripts\activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Enabling the Long Paths can be the potential problem.To solve that,

Steps include:

1. Go to Registry Editor on the Windows Laptop
2. Find the key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"->"SYSTEM"->"CurrentControlSet"->
   "File System"->"LongPathsEnabled" then double click on that option and change the value from 0 to 1.

3.Now try to install the tensorflow it will work.