# Installing tensorflow issue

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I am trying to install tensorflow. I have downloaded python 3.5 64 bit. It is on my path. I also have python 3.6 32 bit and python 2.7 32 bit. I want to install with pip but whenever I do this I get this error

> Collecting tensorflow
>         Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (ons: )
>       No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38896424/5853530

Comment: Why don't you use a virtual environment for this. I remember using virtual environment to install tf on my machine and it worked really fine.

Comment: `pip --version`?

Comment: @hoefling It gives me version 18, but it only says Python 2.7

Comment: @RajeevSingh I've read through that entire thing. None of the commands worked. It helped me figure out I need Python 3.5 64 bit, but that's all I know

Comment: So `pip` command is for Python 2.7. Each Python installation you have has its own `pip`. Figure out how to call `pip` for the Python version you're targeting, probably `py -3.5 -m pip install tensorflow` if you're on windows.

Comment: @hoefling okay that part helped get it installing! However, I got this error `Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\User1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.` 
Should I run the command line as an admin to resolve the issue? This is after I tried to install tensorflow-gpu

Comment: Try adding `--user` to the install command. If it doesn't help, run the terminal as administrator. However, I'm not familiar with windows that much to give a proper advice about resolving permission issues.