# Tensorflow installation Mac error: unable to find matching distribution

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, neural-network, pip

I am attempting to install TensorFlow on my Macintosh computer. I was following the instructions as provided on their website when I reached a problem. I had established a virtual environment in the MacOS terminal and attempted to use pip to install TensorFlow with the command

```
pip install tensorflow
```

when I received the following message:

```
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

How can I resolve this? Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Sincerely, 
Suren Grigorian

Comment: What is your Python version?

Comment: My Python version is version 3.6.2.

Comment: 32 bit or 64? Tensorflow requires 64 bit.

Comment: My version is 64-bit.

Comment: Perhaps this other question might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip

Answer (score 0):

try updating pip using
python3 -m pip3 install --upgrade pip3
and try again by specifying tensorflow version with
pip3 install tensorflow==2.3.1

Comment: Please improve the formatting. The answer then becomes easier to read.