# Pip3 won't update Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been trying to upgrade tensorflow on my Apple OS to the newest version. I used the following command

```
pip3.6 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

and received the following message

```
Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: protobuf==3.1.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.11.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wheel>=0.26 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.32.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.10.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from protobuf==3.1.0->tensorflow) (40.6.2)
```

I believe that 0.12.0 is not the latest version of Tensorflow? Is there a way to get pip3.6 to update install tensorflow? I have already tried uninstalling and then reinstalling - which is an issue in itself. When I installed and used the following command

`pip3.6 install --user --upgrade tensorflow`

I received the following error

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

I have also tried (from: [TensorFlow not found using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip))

`python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl`

to install, which works but this installs 0.12.0. I switched the 0.12.0 with 1.10.0 in the URL and while the installation worked, I got this error when importing tensorflow

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help
```

Is there any solution to this problem?

Thanks

**Update:**

After seeing (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10107), it seems that TF >= 1.10.0 doesn't work for this issue. Trying 1.9.0 worked:

```
python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried in my Mac and there is no problem at all for pip to find the latest tensorflow

Here is my pip version:
pip3.7 --19.0.3

```
$ pip install --user --upgrade tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d5/1c/3ac472009a5c54ae7ec5a3294520ca36d1908cd1e5cf3e3fd923f9b7b31f/tensorflow-1.13.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl (73.6MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 73.6MB 62.2MB/s
Collecting tensorboard<1.14.0,>=1.13.0 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/39/bdd75b08a6fba41f098b6cb091b9e8c7a80e1b4d679a581a0ccd17b10373/tensorboard-1.13.1-py3-none-any.whl (3.2MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.2MB 38.7MB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Collecting protobuf>=3.6.1 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/ed/e53989e7b08274334ddb41dac51294d270b3db7b3d1e354f5b548714c7c6/protobuf-3.8.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (1.4MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 48.1MB/s
Collecting astor>=0.6.0 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/4f/950dfae467b384fc96bc6469de25d832534f6b4441033c39f914efd13418/astor-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.12.0)
Collecting absl-py>=0.1.6 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/3f/9b0355080b81b15ba6a9ffcf1f5ea39e307a2778b2f2dc8694724e8abd5b/absl-py-0.7.1.tar.gz (99kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 21.0MB/s
Collecting tensorflow-estimator<1.14.0rc0,>=1.13.0 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/48/13f49fc3fa0fdf916aa1419013bb8f2ad09674c275b4046d5ee669a46873/tensorflow_estimator-1.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (367kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 368kB 34.3MB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.16.1)
Collecting keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/6a/8c1f62c37212d9fc441a7e26736df51ce6f0e38455816445471f10da4f0a/Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 13.4MB/s
Collecting grpcio>=1.8.6 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/71/92d142dcc3337dbafb6f1d936b19b94a1f65efc9bc3ddfb2315710068025/grpcio-1.21.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (2.0MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.0MB 24.7MB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wheel>=0.26 in ./Python/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.33.1)
Collecting keras-applications>=1.0.6 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/e3/19762fdfc62877ae9102edf6342d71b28fbfd9dea3d2f96a882ce099b03f/Keras_Applications-1.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (50kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 20.2MB/s
Collecting gast>=0.2.0 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/35/11749bf99b2d4e3cceb4d55ca22590b0d7c2c62b9de38ac4a4a7f4687421/gast-0.2.2.tar.gz
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.15 (from tensorboard<1.14.0,>=1.13.0->tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/57/92a497e38161ce40606c27a86759c6b92dd34fcdb33f64171ec559257c02/Werkzeug-0.15.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (327kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 327kB 42.3MB/s
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8 (from tensorboard<1.14.0,>=1.13.0->tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/4e/fd492e91abdc2d2fcb70ef453064d980688762079397f779758e055f6575/Markdown-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (87kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 22.8MB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in ./Python/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from protobuf>=3.6.1->tensorflow) (41.0.1)
Collecting mock>=2.0.0 (from tensorflow-estimator<1.14.0rc0,>=1.13.0->tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/d2/f94e68be6b17f46d2c353564da56e6fb89ef09faeeff3313a046cb810ca9/mock-3.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting h5py (from keras-applications>=1.0.6->tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/c5/eec74d7324628f1b640c6e706981c4ed51afcaa1656ece26cb08d862598e/h5py-2.9.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (6.2MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 6.2MB 43.1MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: absl-py, gast
  Building wheel for absl-py (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/xinyao/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/ee/98/38/46cbcc5a93cfea5492d19c38562691ddb23b940176c14f7b48
  Building wheel for gast (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/xinyao/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/5c/2e/7e/a1d4d4fcebe6c381f378ce7743a3ced3699feb89bcfbdadadd
Successfully built absl-py gast
Installing collected packages: grpcio, protobuf, werkzeug, absl-py, markdown, tensorboard, astor, mock, tensorflow-estimator, keras-preprocessing, h5py, keras-applications, gast, tensorflow
  WARNING: The script markdown_py is installed in '/Users/xinyao/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script tensorboard is installed in '/Users/xinyao/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts freeze_graph, saved_model_cli, tensorboard, tf_upgrade_v2, tflite_convert, toco and toco_from_protos are installed in '/Users/xinyao/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed absl-py-0.7.1 astor-0.8.0 gast-0.2.2 grpcio-1.21.1 h5py-2.9.0 keras-applications-1.0.8 keras-preprocessing-1.1.0 markdown-3.1.1 mock-3.0.5 protobuf-3.8.0 tensorboard-1.13.1 tensorflow-1.13.1 tensorflow-estimator-1.13.0 werkzeug-0.15.4
```

Maybe you should try to upgrade your python3.6 to python3.7?