# Problem with tensorflow while downloading rasa_core

Tags: rasa-core

I’m trying to update the rasa bot source code from a friend of mine but I had a problem when trying to download rasa_core:

```
(cha_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\Chatbot_RASA_room_reservation>pip install rasa_core
Collecting rasa_core
 ...
Collecting tensorflow==1.10.0 (from rasa_core)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.10.0 (from rasa_core) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.10.0 (from rasa_core)
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Do you have any idea ? Is it because of the requirements ?

I tried to install tensorflow according [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip) :

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

But I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing this issue when my colleague was installing it rasa_core. Try installing tensorflow separately then continue with rasa_core installation. It should solve the problem

```
pip install tensorflow
```

If you get *No matching distribution found for tensorflow* error try following:

**Note**: This works for 64 bit Windows for tensorflow version 1.12.0. For all the variants of tensorflow distribution please check https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/

```
python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-1.12.0-rc2.zip
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpI get `No matching distribution found for tensorflow` I' going to check on their website. If you have any other hint let me know !

Comment: I have updated my answer for tensorflow distribution was not found error.