# Installing OpenVino generate error related to tensor-flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, openvino

I a trying to install the latest version of Opevino on my system. I am following this documentation:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/OpenVINO-Install-Windows

In the step that I need to run this batch file: install_prerequisites.bat

and I am getting this error:

```
C:\local\Intel\computer_vision_sdk\deployment_tools\model_optimizer\install_prerequisites>install_prerequisites.bat
Python 3.7.1
ECHO is off.
Collecting tensorflow==1.9.0 (from -r ..\requirements.txt (line 1))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.9.0 (from -r ..\requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.9.0 (from -r ..\requirements.txt (line 1))
*****************************************************************************************
Warning: please expect that Model Optimizer conversion might be slow.
You can boost conversion speed by installing protobuf-*.egg located in the
"model-optimizer\install_prerequisites" folder or building protobuf library from sources.
For more information please refer to Model Optimizer FAQ, question #80.
```

How can I fix this error?

As a side note, when I searched for this error, I found that it relates to PIP 18 and tensorflow: [TensorFlow not found using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip?page=2&tab=Votes)

Answer (score 0):

OpenVINO does not support Python 3.7, this might also explain your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6.5 with pip is required to run the Model Optimizer.
Use these steps to install the correct version of the Python software.

Go to the Python 3.6.5 download page and click Windows x86-64 executable installer to download the executable file. The file is saved as python-3.6.5-amd64.exe in your Downloads folder.

Browse to download Python

Double-click the file to launch the installation.

Make sure the top of the screen shows Python 3.6.5 (64-bit).

IMPORTANT: At the bottom of the install screen, select Add Python 3.6 to PATH.

Install Python and select environment variable option

Click Install Now near the top of the install screen and let the installation complete.

When the installation finishes, click Close.

Please verify that, the above steps are done.