# How to fix ' ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras' importing ImagePrediction?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to run tensorflow for image recognition. I have followed all the steps for it and both keras and tensorflow are installed on my computer.
Steps in this post: https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/ 
But when I try:
from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction

I keep getting the error:
    from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing import image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras'

I think the error comes from my installation of 'tensorflow'. When I tried the method:
 pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow 
I got the error:
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow

So I used instead:
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl

I got it from this post: [TensorFlow not found using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip)

My guess is that the first error drives me to the second, but I don't know how to fix any of them.

Any suggestions?

My code until the problem is:

import tensorflow

from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction

Comment: That version of TensorFlow does not have Keras, it is just too old, you should install at least TensorFlow 1.0

Comment: Can you try pip3 install tensorflow==2.1, if it successfully installs then try "import tensorflow as tf". Then import image as "from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image:". One suggestion is please don't use "from tensorflow.python.*" as that is private to tensorflow and could change or affect other imported modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try writing

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
```

Instead of

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing import image
```

And do the same with all Keras calls.

Comment: tensorflow and tensorflow.keras are not exactly the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the latest version of tensorflow (2.0)

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessessing.text import Tokenizer
```