# Pip Install Tensorflow Failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am trying to install tensorflow in python using pip command as
`pip install tensorflow`
, but unfortunately, I received the following error:
`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow`
I have also tried to install tensorflow using the following command 
`pip install --upgrade
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`, but was again faced with the following error:
`tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`. Additionally, I have checked the same commands against Python Version 3.5x 3.6x and obviously 3.7 as well, but those didn't work.

Comment: I think it might be useful to add some information about your configuration.

Comment: Try tensorflow with anaconda. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow

Comment: Try to install latest version once again, TensorFlow 1.13.0 that supports python 3.7 is just released (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TensorFlow not found using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip)

Answer (score 2):

I think Tensorflow does not currently have support for Python 3.7 and if you have Python 3.7 currently installed this might be the cause of the error message `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

You can downgrade to Python 3.6.x and install tensorflow using pip then.

Comment: As mentioned above i have tried downgrading and tested on python 3.5 and 3.6

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are capitalizing/spelling properly? The command prompt is case-sensitive. The input I use is:
`cd C:\path\to\the\directory\python\is\installed\in` (cd, space, the path to the directory) then:
`python -m pip install TensorFlow`
It should work afterwards.

Comment: Directory are perfect and working  on other libraries i have installed  other libraries on same  directory..

Comment: Make sure that you are capitalizing properly. Copy and paste my version "TensorFlow" (with T and F capitalized) and try again

Comment: Ok then you can ignore second sentence of my above answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on windows 10, I find out that tensorflow work with python x64 installation and the command I used is the follow:

> pip install --upgrade tf

Comment: This will install "Randomised true or false values" - https://pypi.org/project/tf/

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow works with 64bit as of now.

if you are wondering from where can u get that : 
https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

select x84-64 version (64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

Type on command line(If you are using GPU version)

```
pip install -U --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

or If you are using CPU only

```
pip install -U --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: try downgrading to python3.5 and then try this one ' pip install tf-nightly '

Comment: downgraded till 3.5 should i downgrade more ? @younesh

Comment: try :   pip install tf-nightly

Comment: yes tried all four version pip install tensorflow 2) pip install tf-nightly 3)pip install tensorflow-gpu 4) 
pip install tf-nightly-gpu

Comment: check weather your python is 64  or 32 bit  and make sure it must be 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

I believe if all of you used this command, the problem is going to be solved finally.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the [pip install guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip). It describes the process and also highlights the workarounds to take for various python versions and different Operating Systems.

I had a mac with an M1 chip and the installation instructions were slightly different. I had to use anaconda to install TensorFlow. Ensure you have python version 3.7+ with a 64-bit architecture.

Download and install [Conda env](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh).

```
chmod +x ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
sh ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
source ~/miniforge3/bin/activate
```

Install the TensorFlow dependencies:

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps==2.6.0
```

Install base TensorFlow:

```
python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
```

Install tensorflow-metal plugin

```
python -m pip install tensorflow-metal
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue using MacOs M1 Ventura 13.1
this fixes the problem:

`python3 -m pip install tensorflow-macos`