# Tensorflow installation error: No module named _pywarp_tensorflow

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, installation, tensorboard

I installed tensorflow using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip) link on StackOverflow.

But, when I tried to run my code, I got the error below

This is my system's information

```
(env) PS C:\SD\project> python --version
Python 3.7.3
(env) PS C:\SD\AnomalyDetectionCVPR2018> pip3 --version
pip 19.1.1 from c:\sd\env\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

The error that I got:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SD\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\SD\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\SD\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error
```

What am I doing wrong? So far I've used Python and pip with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

again, I had the same problems that you have now, I tryed install tensorflow in windows7, windows 8 and 10 inclusive in virtual machinnes, the same problem was for matplotlib. 
My solution was remove my python version and I installed **Anaconda**,

Try to install `Anaconda3-4.4.0-Windows-x86_64` or `Anaconda3-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh` for linux, this version was released in 2017-05-26.

[Anacoda versions](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/)

And then try to install tensorflow, matplotlib, pandas, numpy but before run

```
conda update conda
```

To update some packages of anaconda. And you will install those the packages/libraries without problems,
Best Regards