# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I want to install tensorflow to  use Keras LSTM
I installed Keras, and i import this lines to my code.

```
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
```

Error is when runnig the code:

```
No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Cmd error when i write "pip install tensorflow" :

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Pip version is 19.3 , python version 3.7

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro vscode

Comment: Thats not the platform, I mean operating system, computer architecture, etc

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro  windows 10

Comment: @ŞevvalKahraman is your OS/computer a 32-bit or 64-bit architecture??

Comment: @stephen_mugisha 64 bit

Comment: try runnning ```py -m pip install --upgrade pip``` and then ```py -m pip install tensorflow```

Comment: i tried but it didnt worked

Comment: Are you running the code on the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: @ŞevvalKahraman Please help future visitors by keeping this post better organized: up-vote the answers that are helpful and/or select the one that solved your problem by clicking on the checkbox near it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On **Windows**, you must use [Python 3.7.6 (64 bits)](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.6/python-3.7.6-amd64.exe) (or later version, provided it is 64-bits) to install **tensorflow**:

```
C:\Program Files\Python-3.7.6-x64> python.exe -m pip install --user tensorflow
```

Unfortunately, the 32-bit version is not supported by tensorflow and will give you that nasty error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

A few important notes:

- Install [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable packages for x64](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe) (2015, 2017, 2019).
- If you have previously installed Python 3.7 for x86, uninstall it from your system and also delete the directory where the x86 packages were stored to avoid a conflict with the new x64 packages that will be placed there. In my machine they were stored at `C:\\Users\\karlphillip\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages`.
- Finally, install Python 3.7.6 **(x64)** and upgrade pip with `python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip`.
- Now, simply install tensorflow: `python -m pip install --user tensorflow`

Comment: You save jobs!!

Answer (score 3):

> **Solution**

I figured out that the issue is with the Python version.

- ie : python 3.8.1 doesn't have the support for Tensorflow 3.8.1

So I downgraded Python version from 3.8.1 to 3.7.6
Later I worked fine

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

> My System Specification

- Windows 10
- python 3.8.1
- pip 19.3.1

Comment: Still couldn't figureout the actuall cause for the error I got earlier when using "pip install tensorflow"

Comment: What is `Tensorflow 3.8.1` ?? The current version is 2.7.0 (and it's 2 years after your answer :) )

Answer (score 2):

For others who faced this problem, TensorFlow might not support the version you are running yet. At the time of writing, you will get the same error when running Python 3.9 and trying to install TensorFlow. You need to ensure your Python version is supported by TensorFlow.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/

> TensorFlow is tested and supported on the following 64-bit systems:
>
> - Python 3.5–3.8

I then used a different python. i.e. `python3.8 -m pip install tensorflow==2.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

Hi writing my suggestions here because i can't commment yet.

Could you try to look if you have the right python version installed? Sometimes something went wrong and a 32-bit version of python is installed. But tensorflow only works with the 64 bit verison of python. You can check your python version with the following comand into the python interpreter

```
import struct
print struct.calcsize("P") * 8
```

It should print "64".

It generally seems that there is a problem with python 3.7 and tensorflow ([here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17022))

For some people there it helped to install a specific tensorflow version

```
pip install tensorflow==1.14.0
```

as also seen [here.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25054)

Also a solution might be to downgrade to phyton 3.6.

For 3.6:
Another possible solution can be found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip) (For Windows only for Python 3.6 as of the date of this answer)

TLDR: The most upvoted answer suggestes to try following input (for python 3.6 CPU-only)

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

I hope this helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This solution always worked for me.

1) Figure out what Python interpreter you are actually using

```
import sys
print(sys.executable) #prints "path_to_python"
```

2) On the terminal run: `"path_to_python" -m pip install tensorflow`
where `"path_to_python"` is the output you got before, obviously.