# pip3 install tensorflow-gpu installs tensorflow version 1.14.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to install Tensorflow 2.0. These are the commands that I am running:

```
$ pip3 install tensorflow-gpu
```

When I open a Python Console (in Jetbrains PyCharm)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
```

I'm immediately hit with a bunch of deprecation warnings:

```
/home/jason/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/jason/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/jason/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/jason/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/jason/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/jason/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
/home/jason/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/jason/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/jason/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/jason/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/jason/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/jason/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/jason/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-C/ch-0/193.5233.109/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py:178: The name tf.AUTO_REUSE is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/jason/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-C/ch-0/193.5233.109/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py:178: The name tf.AttrValue is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.AttrValue instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/jason/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-C/ch-0/193.5233.109/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py:178: The name tf.COMPILER_VERSION is deprecated. Please use tf.version.COMPILER_VERSION instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/jason/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-C/ch-0/193.5233.109/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py:178: The name tf.CXX11_ABI_FLAG is deprecated. Please use tf.sysconfig.CXX11_ABI_FLAG instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/jason/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-C/ch-0/193.5233.109/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py:178: The name tf.ConditionalAccumulator is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.ConditionalAccumulator instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.
```

When I try to check the version of Tensorflow via:

```py
tf.__version__
```

It outputs:

```
'1.14.0'
```

I am new to Python, and I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip/42596864#42596864) I had the same issue and this worked well for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu>=2`

I really don't have an explanation why it doesn't install 2.0 normally. There shouldn't be any difference between these commands, but this one worked and `pip3 install` did not.

Also, it is a good idea to update pip itself first:

`pip3 install --upgrade pip`

**UPD, root cause:**
TF2 requires pip 19. Simple pip upgrade should help in most cases.

In addition, in one of recent versions pip3 executable was corrupted, which was fixed by using `python3 -m pip`. This issue is already fixed.

Comment: I updated my pip3. Then I got a permission denied error, so I created a virtual environment using https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/236. However, it is still only installing v 1.14.0.

Comment: What's your `$ pip3 --version?` Mine is `pip 9.0.1`.

Comment: Okay I managed to upgrade pip3 to version 19.3.1 from 9.0.1 and `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu` installs tensorflow-gpu version 2.0.0.