# Can I install Tensorflow gpu without nvidia graphic card?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to this project for my school https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COlbP62-B-U
Everything worked smooth till i encountered that pip install tensorflow doesn't work.
then I tried this for install tensorflow [TensorFlow not found using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip). I could successfully install tensorflow but still tensorflow-gpu couldn't be install.

Any idea how can I do that.

Comment: No, you cannot. If you want to know why, because tensorflow gpu requires a compatible gpu.

Answer (score 3):

Updated for tensorflow 2:

Tensorflow 2.x

There is no separate installation for tensorflow GPU in 2.x, it's a unified installation for both CPU and GPU. The package will be built with GPU support if and only if a compatible GPU is available. To verify, use the command:
`tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()` after installing.
[Source](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/is_built_with_cuda)

Note that you still need a compatible GPU first.

---

Tensorflow 1.x:

No, you need a compatible GPU to install tensorflow-GPU.

From the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#hardware_requirements).

> Hardware requirements: NVIDIA® GPU card with CUDA® Compute Capability
> 3.5 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use Google Colab (https://colab.research.google.com), which has the option of using GPUs in the notebooks.

Comment: How i am supposed to link a file located in my local drive. My tensor flow model and protoc files are available in D drive of pc.

Answer (score 0):

No, you Can not install Tensorflow gpu without nvidia graphic card.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot, its like installing a soul without body.
But if you are a curious learner and want to try something amazing with DL try buying GPU-compute instances on Cloud or try out **Google Colab**.