# pycharm can't install Tensorflow on windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, virtualenv

I try to

```
pip install --user --upgrade pip

pip install tensorflow

pip3 install tensorflow
```

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRalJ.png)

[Add python interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akSe3.png)

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYkGw.png)

[RunDebugConfigurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxllS.png)

Available packages
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySWJi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ravisut,

You seem to be entering right commands. Based on your inputs it looks like you have a 32-bit Python version installed. Tensorflow is only supported on Python 64-bit. So install the 64-bit version of Python and try again.

After that if you still have issues - try this thread: [TensorFlow not found using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip)

In particular, try installing with whl file:
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
you may need to pick relevant TF version () here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: Thank you i install Python 3.7 64-bit and pip install tensorflow ...are Successfully

Answer (score 0):

install Python 3.7 64-bit and pip install tensorflow ...are Successfully

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYcSL.png)