# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.7.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install tensorflow-gpu ver. 1.7.0 on a virtual environment using pip. My python version is 2.7.12, and my OS is Scientific Linux ver. 7.4 (Nitrogen). When I try the following

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.7.0
```

I get the following errors:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.7.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.7.0
```

Help?

Comment: I'm afraid that the version is no longer available in the repo. I just have tried `pip install tensorflow-gpu==` and see the list of available versions.

Comment: My bad, I'm using Python 3.7. Maybe you would like to do more specific by doing `python2 -m pip install tensorflow-gpu==`

Comment: when I run the command you provided I just get the same errors, it doesn't give me a list of the available versions

Comment: Check if you have installed 32 bit version of python. Tensorflow need a 64-bit python installed, it does not work on 32-bit python installation.

Comment: For me, I got `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu== (from versions: 0.12.0rc0, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0, 1.15.0rc0, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0rc3, 1.15.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0rc0, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.1.0rc0, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0rc2, 2.1.0)`.

Comment: @n1colas.m I have the 64 bit version installed

Comment: @NaufanRusydaFaikar for me it just says "from versions: none" like in my original post

Comment: What's the version of yours `pip`?

Comment: @NaufanRusydaFaikar 20.0.2

Comment: Have tried to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip?

Comment: @NaufanRusydaFaikar it looks like all of those answers have to do with tensorflow and not tensorflow-gpu, which, since my tensorflow version is 1.7.0, are two different things. I successfully installed tensorflow v. 1.7.0, I just need tensorflow-gpu

Comment: I forgot to face this a few years ago. Sorry if I cannot help much, maybe you would like to download the `.whl` file manually from https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/1.7.0/#files and install it just by typing `pip install <filename>`.

Comment: @NaufanRusydaFaikar when I try that I get "ERROR: tensorflow_gpu-1.7.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Comment: What do you get when executing `python2 -c "from pip._internal.pep425tags import get_supported; print(get_supported()[0])"` in the terminal?

Comment: @hoefling cp27-cp27m-manylinux2014_x86_64

Answer (score 1):

If

```
$ python2 -c "from pip._internal.pep425tags import get_supported; print(get_supported()[0])"
```

returns `cp27-cp27m-manylinux2014_x86_64`, it means that your distro ships Python 2.7 compiled without wide unicode support. `tensorflow` supports only Python 2.7 compiled with wide unicode support (tag `cp27-cp27mu-...`), is thus not installable with the default Python 2.7. Either switch to Python 3 (supports wide unicode by default), or compile Python 2.7 from source, passing the `--enable-unicode=ucs4` to `configure` script.