# How do I download tensorflow on pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pycharm

I'm trying to install tensorflow in Pycharm, but typing `pip install tensorflow` isn't working. I'd prefer not to download anaconda.. any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Elaborate "*isn't working*", plz.

Comment: it returns the following error:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: [Latest tensorflow](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.2.0/#files) supports Python 3.5-3.8 but only 64-bit Python. Verify you have 64-bit Python.

Comment: sorry.. how do I do that?

Comment: `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`

Comment: It does indeed say 32, thank you! I've changed it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're typing that in `terminal`? [image]

Also, you don't need anaconda to install anything. You can just type `pip install tensorflow` using CLI.

Comment: I typed 'pip install TensorFlow' it in the terminal (double-checked it). It returns the following error:
'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow'

Comment: @Chan Like @phd said, make sure you are using 64-bit Python. Here is a similar question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip`

Comment: @Chan You're welcome! You can mark this post as an answer if it helped you