# Tensorflow installing error: __ is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install tensorflow on my PC but I keep getting errors.

I have seen multiple posts about tensorflow installing errors online but all I found was solutions saying that the version of python was not compatible. However, I am using python 3.8 and I am using the URL for python 3.8 provided on tensorflow's website, so I don't see how that could be the issue.

The command I'm using:

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

The error I'm getting:

```sh
ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I'm using `python 3.8`, `pip 20.1.1` and my PC is running 64 bit Windows 10.

From tensorflow's website, the requirements are :

- Python 3.5-3.8
- pip 19.0 or later
- Windows 7 or later

Which are all satisfied.

Why am I getting this error?

EDIT: using only `pip install tensorflow` gets me the following errors:

```sh
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Comment: Could you check whether your version of python is 64bit? You can check by opening the interpreter and looking for either 32bit or amd64

Comment: why no `pip install tensorflow`?

Comment: @viewed: Before tensorflow was in PyPI, it had to be included via url, this could be a reason.
This question could be duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/q/38896424/4575793 - especially consider answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/41084963/4575793

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely you're using the 32bit version of python 3.8 instead of the 64bit version. You can check by opening the interpreter and looking at the first line. If it has `32 bit (Intel)` or something similar, then it would be the 32 bit version. To get the 64bit edition, scroll down to Files on this link https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/ and pick up the x86-64 version.

Comment: Another possibility (if you're on a system that uses multiple versions of python, like me) is that the version you're installing for needs to be the default python version. Even if you install with `pip3.8` you still need to change the default python version.