# Problems installing tensorflow (not a supported wheel on this platform)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install TensorFlow using pip  `pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`

However, I got this error message `ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`
Is it because my CPU is intel? Since the link put amd64

I have looked at [TensorFlow not found using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip)
and followed the steps but I still can't download it.

Comment: No, confusingly, Intel are amd64 However, it's likely that either you have 32-bit Python installed, or it isn't Python 3.8.

Comment: @Grismar I downloaded 64 bit Python, it can download successfully. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Using 64-bit is almost always better anyway. 32-bit can be slightly faster in specific cases, because some data is smaller, but 64-bit allows you to address over 2Gb of data without overhead and in today's world, that's a fairly common requirement. With 32-bit, you'd need to jump through lots of hoops to make that work.