# Unable to install tensorflow module in Python3

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm installing tensorflow. My system has the following specifications:

```
py --version
Python 3.8.2
```

I tried the following commands to install tensorflow module

```
py -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

```
py -m pip install tensorflow==2.2
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.2
```

```
py -m pip install tensorflow==2.2.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.2.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.2.0
```

What can I do to install this successfully on my machine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TensorFlow not found using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip)

Comment: @Jacques Yes. Thanks! Looks like I'm using Python for 32-bit. TF works only with 64-bit. So trying that out.

Comment: did you use this command too: "pip install tensorflow==2.2.0" ?

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow supports only 64-bit system architecture. Hence it shows compatibility issue in 32-bit and no matching distribution found.