# What to do if pip can't find right versions from requirements.txt

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I have found a [github repo](https://github.com/krasserm/face-recognition) and cloned it, created and activated a venv, and then attempted to install the requirements from the requirements.txt

In this example, pip fails, saying:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 54)) (from versions: 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.15.0rc0, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0rc3, 1.15.0, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0rc0, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.1.0rc0, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0rc2, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.2.0rc0, 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0)
```

This has happened to me in the past too, with a completely different project using the same tensorflow version.

1. Why is this tf version not in the list? Did the tf authors remove versions? Where can I find it?
2. How do I troubleshoot these situations in the future?

It just seems silly that the whole point in a venv and requirements.txt is to make sure I'm running the exact same packages and versions that the author has, but it trips up at the first hurdle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TensorFlow not found using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip)

Comment: Which version of python are you using? TensorFlow 1.5.0 only supports python 2.7 and 3.3-3.6. See https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.5.0/#files

Answer (score 0):

if the package is not available on pypi, you need to manually download and install from the github repo or where ever it exists.

This is a problem probably concerning Tensorflow already described here:
[TensorFlow not found using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to OP's version of Python. TensorFlow 1.5.0 was released on January 26, 2018 and supports Python versions 2.7 and 3.3-3.6. The solution is to use a supported Python version. Python 3.7+ is not supported because Python 3.7 was released on June 27, 2018, after the release of TensorFlow 1.5.0.

See the [TensorFlow 1.5.0 PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.5.0/#files) for more information.

Comment: Is there an easy way to find out what version of Python this github repo uses? I initially tried 3.8 and 3.7, then on your advice installed 2.7 and that that doesn't work either (this time because of jupyter notebook version not being compatible). I can't find what python version the author of the github repo used.

Comment: Make a virtual environment with python 3.6 and install jupyter notebook into that. Then try to use the github repo.