# Tensorflow 1.5.4 not available via pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I would like to install 1.5.4 version of the tensorflow library, but the package is not available via pip even though the [PyPi site lists](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.15.4/) this version. I must be missing something obvious. Thanks for the help.

I tried the following:

```
$ docker run -ti python:2.7 /bin/bash
root@b3b8132c3ed3:/# pip install --upgrade pip
[...]
Successfully installed pip-20.2.3
root@b3b8132c3ed3:/# pip install --upgrade setuptools
[...]
Successfully installed setuptools-44.1.1
root@b3b8132c3ed3:/# pip install tensorflow==1.15.4
[...]
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15.4 (from versions: 0.12.0rc0, 0.12.0rc1, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0rc0, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.15.0rc0, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0rc3, 1.15.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0rc0, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.1.0rc0, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0rc2, 2.1.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15.4
```

UPDATE:

The ultimate answer is that TensorFlow project as of [January 2020 does not support Python 2.7 anymore](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/g/announce/c/gVwS5RC8mds/m/dCt1ka2XAAAJ)

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate of [TensorFlow not found using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip). If you disagree, let me know, I'll remove my vote.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the System Requirements listed [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip), I don't think Python 2.7 is supported. I hit the same error when I tried to install `tensorflow==1.15.4` for Python 3.8 (which is also not supported). When I downgraded to Python 3.7 it worked.

Also, if you haven't seen them, there are [Tensorflow Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow) that might fit your need, though I find the tagging a little confusing. Based on the info on that page, it sounds like they no longer are making python 2 images, but [this one](https://hub.docker.com/layers/tensorflow/tensorflow/1.15.0/images/sha256-347a9da65b6eaf4d233d3b639f345a055e6f03c4535e92d60dc30c7ab55023f9?context=explore) might have been the last python2/CPU image?

I suppose as another route, since they seem to have an image that runs 1.15.0 with python 2, maybe version 1.15.0 will work for you.