# I had trouble installing Python deepimagesearch library

Tags: python, installation, pip

> when i try to install deepimagesearch library This problem arises

```
            Collecting DeepImageSearch
        Using cached DeepImageSearch-1.3.tar.gz (6.4 kB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
        Using cached DeepImageSearch-1.2.tar.gz (6.3 kB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
        Using cached DeepImageSearch-1.1.tar.gz (6.3 kB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
        Using cached DeepImageSearch-1.0.tar.gz (6.3 kB)
    Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done 
ERROR: Cannot install deepimagesearch==1.0, deepimagesearch==1.1, deepimagesearch==1.2, deepimagesearch==1.3 and deepimagesearch==1.4 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
    The conflict is caused by:
    deepimagesearch 1.4 depends on tensorflow
    deepimagesearch 1.3 depends on tensorflow
    deepimagesearch 1.2 depends on tensorflow
    deepimagesearch 1.1 depends on tensorflow
    deepimagesearch 1.0 depends on tensorflow
```

> How should I solve it?

Comment: its fixed i just use python 3.7 and its worked in this version

Answer (score 0):

as per `requirements.txt` [file](https://github.com/TechyNilesh/DeepImageSearch/blob/main/DeepImageSearch/requirements.txt) from github repo, installing  `tensorflow==2.3.2` could resolve the conflict

try

```
pip install tensorflow==2.3.2
```

Comment: This is exactly the problem when i want install tensorflow i get this error 

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)                         ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

installing this will resolve the conflict for me. the enter code here solution was found on this thread: [TensorFlow not found using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip)

```
`python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl`
```