# Need help installing TensorFlow/Keras. And h5py and hdp5

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hdf5, h5py

I want to use keras in Jupyter. Running command "import tensorflow as tf" tells me that tensorflow cannot be found. "pip install tensorflow" says tensorflow cannot be found. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip) i got a better command:

```
py -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

This worked better, because this time there was progess. But an error was encountered - failed to build wheel for h5py. HDF5 dependency could not be loaded. Trying to get h5py with pip gives exact same error: cant build wheel because hdf5 is missing.

[This](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/) website does not seem to have anything useful for windows7.
Trying every installer from [here](http://hasyweb.desy.de/services/computing/nexus/hdf5-external-filters/install_on_windows.html) had no effect. While claiming that h5py was "successfully installed", trying to install tensorflow proved the opposite.
And trying to install wheels from [this website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#hdf5plugin) just returned the same error. HDF5 could not be found. **Even thought I was trying to install hdf5.**

[This installation guide](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/build.html) is about h5py. it does not work because i dont have hdf5.

So my question is. How do i get a working keras for jupyter? Where can i find an installer that actually installs what i want? What is the complete set of CMD commands that are guaranteed to work and result in a working Tensor flow?

i am using 64 bit windows7, my python is 3.7.2. This fetch quest of collecting tiny bits and pieces of the answer is driving me mad.

Comment: Have you tried to containerize Jupyter and install the libraries using a requirements.txt file?  I found it easier for some libraries than trying to install through Jupyter.  I used docker for Mac but looks like you would need Docker for Windows.

Comment: Im not installing anything thought jupyter. Im running CDM as admin and, i guess, that makes whatever i install available from anywhere on the disk, at least for python

Comment: The tensorflow wheel you are trying to installs is for mac, not for windows, this will not work.

Comment: i tried a wheel file from the www.lfd.uci.edu, same as in "this website" link. same thing. i need this God forsaken hdf5

Comment: Did you follow instructions for windows from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).  Just make sure that you are installing everything in a new environment to avoid conflicts with base environment's dependencies. You can test the same in WSL2/ Docker container too.